# Does the morpheme “ative”, used as a suffix, transform the word into adjectives or nouns?

Tags: suffixes, morphology

preservative, for instance, can be either used as a noun or an adjective.

> - This kind of food doesn’t contain any kind of **preservatives**
> - the **preservative** effect of freezing is good to keep most of vegetables last long

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suffix *ative* is added to a verb to form an adjective which means "having the ability to do {verb's action}".  Those adjectives can become nouns.

purgative
a purgative

Comment: Some *-ative* adjectives *(purgative, narrative, operative,...)* can also be used as nouns. But others *(tentative, lucrative, evocative,...)* can't. Not sure what if any "rules" might be involved, though.

Comment: I don't believe there are any rules about which adjectives can be nouned, and whether they acquire suffixes or not to do so.

Comment: I believe any such adjective could be "coerced" into a noun in the proper circumstances.  Seems to happen in sci-fi writing rather a lot.  *She was a pensive but her sister was an active.*  I guess we could call such fabricated contexts "coercives".